# Terminology graphs with loops

Tags: graph-theory, terminology, discrete-mathematics

I'm working on a project in which we use a type of undirected graphs where loops (an edge from a vertex to itself) but NOT parallel edges (multiple edges with the same end vertices), and I was wondering if there exists a name for these types of graphs.

I noticed that in the case where parallel edges are allowed, some authors make the distinction between 'multigraphs' and 'pseudographs' to denote whether or not loops are permitted, but I have never seen such a distinction when multiple edges are not allowed.

If anyone has ever come across such a name, I would be gratefull, because it will probably look better than "Let G be a graph that is permitted to have loops".

Answer (score 0):

> A simple graph [[1](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SimpleGraph.html),[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(discrete_mathematics)#Simple_graph)] is an unweighted, undirected graph containing no graph loops or multiple edges.

So you could either use that definition making it explicit the loops are allowed:

```
Let G be an unweighted, undirected graph containing loops but no multiple edges.
```

or could loosen the conditions of a simple graph:

```
Let G be a graph that is simple but may, additionally, contain looping edges.
```